# Viable way to deploy/update internal Office Add-Ins for Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

I've built an office add-in for excel using office.js, angular2, and a manifest file on a share drive. It adds a new ribbon to excel, with custom icons that when clicked either perform various functions or open a taskpane which loads a web app in excel. **I'm wondering if there's a clean, viable way I can distribute it to a few people internally who are also running Excel 2016.**

[This site](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish) lists options for deploying and publishing these add-ins, but it seems geared towards big projects/large organizations. It lists 5 options:

1. **Sideloading** - this is what I currently use for development and feel like it may be my only option for distributing it internally, but this also seems problematic because it seems that when I edit or update my manifest file, each user has to know about it and then manually re-load the add-in to get the most up to date and working version.
2. **Centralized deployment** - I think this is for Office 365 which I don't have. I also do not have Office 2016 ProPlus.
3. **Office Store** - This tool is to be strictly internal so this option will not work.
4. **SharePoint catalog** - This option does not support add-in commands so I can't do this either.
5. **Exchange server** - Not sure about this, assuming this is for Outlook add-ins?

---

So, I guess I'm wondering:

1. Is sideloading my only option?
2. And, if so, is there a clean way I can distribute an excel add-in internally using sideloading while being able to maintain it, extend it, and push updates to it regularly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

share drive and side loading seem like the only options you have. I strongly recommend you to use centralized deployment with Office 365 as this is the only way you can distribute your Add-In to specific users or groups within your organization.

Comment: Thanks. I may have to consider Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ClickOnce.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc176036(v=vs.90).aspx

You can set an internal IP as target. We have a .NET plugin working on Office 2010.

Comment: At a glance, I'm not sure this will work with the latest office.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sideloading` option but you can host your angular website in github or of your choice and change the `source location` and `support url` in the xml file to you domain.

see the below example. I have deployed my app in github with url "s1728k.github.io/myblog" and I am updating my xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
      <Id>040c034b-e3c2-4ab7-8939-e8fc38a51754</Id>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
      <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
      <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
      <DisplayName DefaultValue="Quarterly Sales Report Sample" />
      <Description DefaultValue="Quarterly Sales Report Sample"/>
      <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="Workbook" />
      </Capabilities>
      <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="s1728k.github.io/myblog" />
      </DefaultSettings>
      <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
<Dictionary>

</Dictionary>
     <SupportUrl DefaultValue="s1728k.github.io/myblog" />
      <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png" />
</OfficeApp>
```